# PHP errors not showing in Chrome network tab (but show in Firefox)

Tags: php, google-chrome, error-handling, google-chrome-devtools

The Google Chrome network tab doesn't seem to display PHP errors properly.
Firefox and Insomnia perfectly show all errors, but chrome just shows

> Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given
> identifier

[image: chrome display error]

I've tried setting the headers `'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'` and a lot of other stuff but nothing seems to work.

Code throwing the error:

```
dd('Test'); // With symfony/var-dumper package
// OR
throw new \Exception('Test');
```

My error handler:

```
    $payload = [
        'error' => [
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'code' => $exception->getCode()
        ]
    ];

    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($payload));

    return $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(500);
```

Any ideas how I can do this? I'm using plain PHP, with Laravel and Symfony this is no problem at all.

Comment: How are you making the request from the client side? Also do none of the [existing materials online](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+to+load+response+data%3A+No+data+found+for+resource+with+given+identifier) about this error relate to your situation? For example it could possibly be related to a CORS issue. Is there anything in the Console when this is happening?

Comment: `with Laravel and Symfony this is no problem at all`...not sure the server really has control over this. But if you have "working" code from onel/both of those frameworks then it's possible the comparison might be instructive - if only to rule that out as a coincidence, or just possibly to provide some useful info.

Comment: Thanks for answering! The problem indeed was a CORS issue, I had to set the ´Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *´ header before using ´dd´ or throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome blocked the request due to a CORS issue:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/...' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I solved it by adding the following before the `dd('Test')`:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```